# Processor Type in IDA Python

Tags: ida, idapython, python

While using IDA Python and related code of idaapi, the processor type is not returned correctly. Specially we will have MetaPC instead of the exact processor type. 
This is my code that I used it:

```
info = idaapi.get_inf_structure()
    print info.procName
```

Is there any way to correct this problem??

Comment: metapc *is* the actual default processor module for most x86/x64 binaries. What did you expect to get instead?

Comment: I want the processor type exactly, not default processor module!

Comment: got an  example of what you expected?

Comment: For example, I want the processor type such as ARM or MIPS exactly. Not the default which you are saying metapc.

Comment: how and when are you running the script?

Comment: I wrote it in a separate script an run it :
idaq.exe -A -Sscript.py binary_file

Answer (score 1):

IDA can only know the actual processor type if the file format provides it (e.g. `e_machine` value in the ELF header), or you specify it manually. If you pass a plain binary file, there's no way to for IDA detect the CPU so the default one ("metapc") gets loaded.

A simple solution is to specify the correct CPU type using the `-p` [commandline switch](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/618.shtml), e.g.:

```
ida -pmipsb -A -Sscript.py binary_file
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the correct processor type. Is there any way to identify the processor type correctly?

Comment: that's a different question; feel free to ask a new one